# JShell - prevent enter key to execute Java statement or How to set statement delimiter

Tags: java, jshell

I'm practicing Java APIs in JShell prompt(feature added as part of Java 9).

Is there a way to customize or set custom statement terminator (generally ; in java). Because as soon as I hit ENTER key, the Java statement got executed in JShell prompt.

Please assist me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to execute a block of code, you can choose to start your code with a curly brace `{` and then close it with `}` as well. A pictorial representation:

[image]

Comment: All those `...>` are after I've pressed Enter.